# Flutter ml kit not working , possibly after Catalina update

Tags: flutter

I'm using Flutters mlkit plugin, which was working about 5 days ago. I'm now getting errors in Xcode. I'm not sure if its from Flutter upgrading. I am in the stable channel and my flutter doctor has no issues. I have run Flutter clean and updated my pods, but still get errors. I have also updated my macs OS to Catalina since then and not sure if this is a contributor.

Some of the issues are:

No visible @interface for 'FIRRemoteModel' declares the selector 'initWithName:allowsModelUpdates:initialConditions:updateConditions:'

No visible @interface for 'FIRModelManager' declares the selector 'registerRemoteModel:'

No visible @interface for 'FIRLocalModel' declares the selector 'initWithName:path:'

No visible @interface for 'FIRModelManager' declares the selector 'registerLocalModel:'

No known class method for selector 'modelInterpreterWithOptions:'

[image]

Comment: Is it run "flutter clean"? And run again "flutter build ios".

Comment: @AkioAlex I've done that many times, and then recieve the errors aboive

Comment: I have the same issue after update my dependencies. Do you have a working solution?

Comment: any updates on this issue?